# Compute permanent magnet movement in magnetic field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, magnetostatics

Assume I have tiny magnet particles in vacuum, which are not considered as a points, although they are very tiny. Magnet particles are situated in a uniform magnetic field.

**How can I can describe the movement of the particles?**

---

My try

Lets consider 2D case. Paricles are $4\mu m*2\mu m$ rectangles. I want to model mechanics by the next way:

Consider object as array of vertices that are connected with a thread. Force can be applied only to vertex. Because of vertices are conected, when one moves, it pulls the rest(image below will help to understand)

[image]

If it would be gravity I should define the mass of each vertex, and the gravity field among it. In case of magnetism I am confusing of what should I correspond with each vertices. Note that **the vertices are not elementary particles**, they are just some imaginary parts of the microscoping body(or macroscoping, nevermind), so the Lorentz force can't be applied.

Variants to set to vertices:

- Magnetic inductance $\vec{B}$. Unknown
- Magnetic susceptibility value of the whole body $\chi$. Known for me, $\chi = 3*10^{-6}$
- Assume each vertex is a current loop, to use Amper Law, so I need  the current $I$. Unknown.

So basicly, for 2D case, can somebody who maybe already have been doing the modeling similar to this, figure me in which way should I move?

---

Update 1

Found this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20265/255554.
So the force at a point can be found from the product of magetic moment $\vec{m}$ and magnetic inductance $\vec{B}$ at this point:

$$\vec{F}(x) =  \vec{m}(x)\times \vec{B}(x)$$

To find magnetic moment I have to find, again, the current:

$$m=IS\vec{n}$$

,where $I$ is current of the loop, $S$ is space of the loop, $\vec{n}$ is normal vector to loop plane.

Can megnetic moment can be expressed from magnetic susceptibility value?

---

Update 2

Okay, the relationship between $\chi$ and $\vec{m}$ can be found:

$$\vec{m}=\vec{M}V$$
, where $M$ - magnetization, $V$ - volume
$$\vec{M}=\chi \vec{H}$$
, where $\vec{H}$ - external magnetic field strength
$$\vec{m}= \chi \vec{H} V$$

Although, earlier I considered a 2D case, the volume is known, and equals $95 \mu m^3$, but this is the volume of the whole body, and I need only a small area of vertex, so let it be equal $95/100=0.95 \mu m^3$, and $\vec{H}=100 \frac{A}{m}$, then:

$$\vec{m}=3*10^{-6}\space *\space 100\frac{A}{m}\space *\space 9.5*10^{-19} m^3=2.85*10^{-22} A*m^2$$

**Magnetic moment is found**, now wondering what I should do with $\vec{B}$. Initially, I wanted to set external magnetic field as a magnetic induction field, but now I have to deal with magnetic field strength.

Will it be correct if I define magnetic induction in each point as

$$\vec{B}=\mu_0(\vec{H}+\vec{M})$$?

If yes, I think that’s all

Comment: $m \times B$ is the *torque* on a dipole not the force

Comment: A magnetic dipole does not experience a net force  in a uniform magnetic field.

Comment: @R.W.Bird how much should field not be uniformed? I mean, if it “almost” uniform?

Comment: The net force on a dipole is proportional to the divergence of the field.  A magnetic field spreads most noticeably in the vicinity of the north pole of a magnet.

Comment: @R.W.Bird but the divergence of the magnetic field is zero. And the last sentence, You meant north and south, not exactly north, yes ?

Comment: If the divergence of the field is zero, then there is no net force on a dipole. Some might say that the magnetic field near a S pole is converging.